# What is the best Object based data structure for this hierarchy?

Tags: java

What is the best Object based data structure for this hierarchy

```
"text1"
   |---> "text2"
            |-----> List of objs
```

I could do something like

```
class Test(){
      String text1;
      HashMap<String,List<Obj>> text2ListOfObjs;
}
```

The consumer of this class would do something like

```
for(Test test: tests){
   iterate over hashmap
      ....
}
```

Any other suggestions ?

Comment: without context of what `text1` and `text2` represent I don't see the question clearly here. are `text1` and 'text2` instances of the same class?

Comment: What do they represent? Will there always be exactly one child to text1, and that is text2 with children? How do you need to access the data, and why do you need to access the data?

Comment: Are you trying to represent an XML document?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to map "text1" to "text2" and this to a list of objects, why not just use a nested map: `Map<String, Map<String, List<Obj>>>`?

Comment: Probably because you then wont have a clue on what the strings repesent :)

Comment: Well, I don't know what those strings represent so what should I tell him? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Object oriented designs should convey meaning. You should give us the actual context of this hierarchy instead of the abstract elements. Any data structure could be used to reflect the elements you present, but it would not necessarily be a good design, depending on the meaning,  behavior and context.

A few possible structures:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    Relation relation;
}

class Relation {
    String type;
    List<Person> members;
}
```

For example a Person with name 'Arnie' and a Relation with type "friends" and as members the Persons with names "Bert", "Minnie" and "Joel".

```
class Song {
    String title;
    String composer;
    List<Note> notes;
}
```

Or an even flatter model:

```
Object[] data;
```

which we could instantiate with:

```
data = new Object[] { "text1", "text2", new Object(), new Integer(), new BlaBla() };
```

All these are 'object oriented' models fitting the bill, however which is the best depends on what you are trying to represent and how the system should behave.